# How can I convert arraylist <String> to arraylist <integer>

Tags: java, string, arraylist, integer

My goal is to find on which specific index is String from ArrayList and
add them to new ArrayList,
So if house is [0] than i want to return new ArrayList with integer.

```
public class List {
public static void main(String[] List) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList("house", "bike","dog","house","house"));
    System.out.println(getIntegerArray(words,house));


 public static List<Integer> getIntegerArray(List<String> words, String word) {
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.size() ; i++) {

        }
```

At the begging I have ArrayList like this
Input :

```
["house", "bike","dog"]
```

And I want to get new ArrayList like this
Output:

```
[0,1,2]
```

Comment: The nice thing about `ArrayList` is that you don't need to worry about what size it will be, you can just keep `add`ing things. So what to add? If you want indices over `words`, then you should iterate over `words`. How can you determine whether to add a given index?

Comment: If you try to compile this it will mention there is no variable `house`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it just by checking if the string passed to the method is contained in the list and adding the number to the List `numbers`.

Here an example of the method `getIntegerArray`:

```
public static List<Integer> getIntegerArray(List<String> words, String word) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0; i < words.size() ; i++) {
        if (word.equals(words.get(i)))
            numbers.add(i);
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

PS: in `System.out.println(getIntegerArray(words, house));` you are passing a variable `house` which is not declared. Probably you wanted to write `"house"`.

Comment: Okay, so i just want to check on which index is wanted String and itarate one by one and if the word equal than i add to new array list, but could u explain what exactly do this word.equals(words.get(i)))

Comment: The method String.equals(String) returns a boolean type, true if the strings are the same string, false otherwise.
Note that if there is a difference in the string caused by uppercase and lowercase chars it returns false. If you don't want that to happen use word.equalsIgnoreCase(words.get(i)).

Comment: In the specific case of word.equals(words.get(i)) you are verifying if the string word, passed to the method, is equal to string indexed by i in the for loop.
If true, add the index of the string in the new arraylist, do nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You should not worry about the size of `numbers` list, just add appropriate indexes as needed:

```java
public static List<Integer> getIntegerArray(List<String> words, String word) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0, n = words.size(); i < n; i++) {
        if (Objects.equals(word, words.get(i)))
            numbers.add(i);
    }
    return numbers;
}
```

---

Or use Stream API to get the list of indexes:

```java
public static List<Integer> getIntegerArray(List<String> words, String word) {
    return IntStream.range(0, words.size())
        .filter(i -> Objects.equals(word, words.get(i)))
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`getIntegerArray(List<String> words, String word)` with a single `word` can't get you a list of integers with more than one element, I suggest passing the entire `String[]`, called `findwords` in the code below. Otherwise, lists have a `indexOf()`, which makes things really simple:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
    words.addAll(Arrays.asList("house", "bike","dog","house","house"));
    System.out.println(getIntegerArray(words,args));
}

public static List<Integer> getIntegerArray(List<String> words, String[] findwords) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String word: findwords)
        numbers.add(words.indexOf(word));
    return numbers;
}
```

This will produce `[0, 1, 2]` as output when run with command line arguments `house bike dog`. See https://ideone.com/gYefsa (ideone doesn't support passing command line arguments, so `args` is just initialized inside the code).